# python: defaultdict with non-default argument

Tags: python, dictionary, karma-runner, defaultdict

I want to have something like a `dict` of a `class TestClass` which has a non-default argument. When I access I don't know if the asked-for element came before already. So the `TestClass`:

```
class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.state = 0
    def getName(self):
        self.state = self.state + 1
        return "%s -- %i" % (self.name, self.state)
```

Then the `dict` and the accessing function:

```
db = {}
def getOutput(key):
    # this is a marvel in the world of programming langauges
    if key not in db:
        db[key] = TestClass(key)
    return db[key]
```

And the actual testing code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "testing: %s" % getOutput('charlie').getName()
```

Nice. But I wonder if if there is a more elegant solution. Browsing, the [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) comes into my mind. But this won't work, because I cannot pass an argument to the [default_factory](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict.default_factory):

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(TestClass)
print "testing %s" % d['tom'].getOutput()
```

gives `TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`... I is there another solution?

Besides, I wanna improve my Python. So any other suggestions are welcome as well ;-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `defaultdict` factory indeed does not take an argument.

You can create your own variant that *does* however; the trick is in defining a `__missing__` method:

```
class TestClassDict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        res = self[key] = TestClass(key)
        return res
```

Whenever `dict[key]` is accessed for a non-existing `key`, the `__missing__` method is called. `defaultdict` uses this hook to return `factory()` each time, but you can provide your own and pass in `key`.

Demo:

```
>>> class TestClass(object):
...     def __init__(self, name):
...         self.name = name
...         self.state = 0
...     def getName(self):
...         self.state = self.state + 1
...         return "%s -- %i" % (self.name, self.state)
... 
>>> class TestClassDict(dict):
...     def __missing__(self, key):
...         res = self[key] = TestClass(key)
...         return res
... 
>>> db = TestClassDict()
>>> db['charlie'].getName()
'charlie -- 1'
>>> db
{'charlie': <__main__.TestClass object at 0x102f72250>}
```

Comment: This is really cool and the only answer I could find which easily shows how to do this